# Constructor order in virtual inheritance

Tags: c++

I am a freshman in C++, especially about object-oriented programming. And now I have a problem during my learning.

There is a class hierarchy following:

```
class Class{};

class Base:public Class{};

class Derived1:virtual public Base{};

class Derived2:virtual public Base{};

class MI:public Derived1,public Derived2{};

class Final:public MI,public Class{};
```

And now I want to know what the order of constructor for the definition of a Final class object is.

I draw a diagram:
[image]
[structure of class inheritance http://hi.csdn.net/attachment/201203/16/2712336_1331902452BziD.jpg](http://hi.csdn.net/attachment/201203/16/2712336_1331902452BziD.jpg)

I know Virtual base classes are always constructed prior to nonvirtual base classes regardless of where they appear in the inheritance hierarchy. What I am confused is that if constructor of class Class is before Base, and if constructor of Class is invoked twice. And why?

Can someone tell my the answer? The more detailed, the better.

Comment: It's fairly easy to figure out in a lazy way. Construct a program. Put debug cout statements in each of your constructors (.e.g "I'm Base Constructor!"). Observe the order of construction by following the cout statements.

Comment: warning: direct base `Class` inaccessible in `Final` due to ambiguity

Comment: @0A0D: Of course, that only tells you how the compiler at hand happens to implement it. That may be good enough for you, but maybe it's not. :)

Comment: @0A0D Except that your compiler could be non-compliant, or the behaviour could be undefined by the standard

Comment: @juanchopanza: If its non-compliant, I can't help that. Use gcc.

Comment: @0A0D But you need to know that gcc is compliant w.r.t this issue in the first place for the test to be valid, furthermore, you'd need to know if it is defined by the standard, by which stage you almost know the answer anyway.

Comment: @juanchopanza: Since this is not an implementation defined issue, the whole discussion is moot.

Comment: @0A0D: but to find out that implementations have no freedom here, you have to check the standard, which means you can read what the required behavior is, and the test on GCC is moot. It's only useful if you don't think you understand the language in the standard, and are willing to assume GCC conforms, then you can use it to check a specific case that you can't work out in your head.

Comment: @SteveJessop: According to Herb Sutter, gcc is fairly compliant. You could use Comeau C++ compiler. But at any rate, it's not left up the compiler and one can be confident that gcc will interpret this properly. Therefore, putting the debug statements in there is good for a practical test. If you really wanted to know why, then the standard is important but it isn't exactly a light read and experts should interpret them, not lay programmers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The direct inheritance of `Class` by `Final` and `Base` is not `virtual`, so an instance of `Final` has *two* base class subobjects of type `Class`. The one that is the direct base of `Base` is constructed before `Base`, and the one that is the direct base of `Final` is constructed afterwards (in fact after `MI`).

The reason is that:

1. direct bases are constructed in the order they're listed (unless they're a virtual base that has been constructed already),
2. bases are constructed before the class's own constructor runs.

Applying (1) to `Final` tells us that `Class` is constructed after `MI`. Applying (2) several times tells us that `Class` is constructed before `Base`, before `Derived1` and `Derived2`, before `MI`.